# How to make a hexagonal SVG shape Rounded corner?

Tags: html, css, svg

T created this Codepen to show what I have got -

https://codepen.io/rahul0310/pen/zYBamEJ

I am trying to achieve something like the attached image. I have created a hexagonal progress bar to show the user progress, I have tried the make the svg shape rounded edge but it is not working. Does any one have idea how I can make the svg progress bar round edge like the outer and Avatar image holder hexagonal shapes.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Reference Image]

Comment: In order to change the roundness of the corners you need to connect the sides with arcs (A) or bezier curves (Q). For example given this polygon points `723 314 543 625.77 183 625.77 3 314 183 2.23 543 2.23 723 314`  for a roundness of 30 you may get this path: `M708.000,288.019 Q723,314 708.000,339.981L558.000,599.789 Q543,625.77 513.000,625.770L213.000,625.770 Q183,625.77 168.000,599.789L18.000,339.981 Q3,314 18.000,288.019L168.000,28.211 Q183,2.23 213.000,2.230L513.000,2.230 Q543,2.23 558.000,28.211Z`

Comment: You may use this application to get the roundness you want: https://codepen.io/enxaneta/pen/bJZRPb?editors=0010

Comment: @enxaneta, can you tell me one thing, in the second path of the svg which parameter determines the starting point ?

Comment: I hope I understand you. The starting point for this path this path: `M708.000,288.019 Q723,314 708.000,339.981L558.000,599.789 Q543,625.77 513.000,625.770L213.000,625.770 Q183,625.77 168.000,599.789L18.000,339.981 Q3,314 18.000,288.019L168.000,28.211 Q183,2.23 213.000,2.230L513.000,2.230 Q543,2.23 558.000,28.211Z` is the move to command: `M708.000,288.019`

Comment: @enxaneta, Yes, basically i want to start the progress bar at exact  top point of the hexagon, right now it is starting 2px to 3px early. How you are manipulating the values? any external website?

Comment: In order to do what you need there is a lot of calculation to be done. You need to replace the first quadratic bezier curve with a cuadratic one. Next you need to split this curvein 2 cuadratic bezier. Eventually the d attribute you may look like this: `"M715.5,314 715.5,314C715.5,322.66 713,331.32 708, 339.981L558.000,599.789 Q543,625.77 513.000,625.770L213.000,625.770 Q183,625.77 168.000,599.789L18.000,339.981 Q3,314 18.000,288.019L168.000,28.211 Q183,2.23 213.000,2.230L513.000,2.230 Q543,2.23 558.000,28.211L708,288.019C713, 296.679 715.5,305.34 715.5,314z`

Comment: @enxaneta, almost there, need to make the curve 1 px shorter at start

Comment: I don't understand what are you asking.

Comment: @enxaneta, the last answer you have given is almost right, the starting point of the curve needs to be shorten by 1px, means right now from where it is starting i want to move that point to right by 1px, based on your last answer of the path.

Comment: @enxaneta, if you the see the reference image in the question, from where the green path started, i want to start it from there, if it is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `stroke-linejoin: round` in path to round corner

```js
let max = 2160;
let progress = 80;
document.querySelector(".fill").setAttribute(
  "style",
  "stroke-dashoffset: " + ((100 - progress) / 100) * max
);
```

```css
.user-avatar-holder{
    background: #1D2333;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 25px auto;
    clip-path: polygon(
        47.5% 5.66987%,
        48.2899% 5.30154%,
        49.13176% 5.07596%,
        50% 5%,
        50.86824% 5.07596%,
        51.7101% 5.30154%,
        52.5% 5.66987%,
        87.14102% 25.66987%,
        87.85495% 26.16978%,
        88.47124% 26.78606%,
        88.97114% 27.5%,
        89.33948% 28.2899%,
        89.56505% 29.13176%,
        89.64102% 30%,
        89.64102% 70%,
        89.56505% 70.86824%,
        89.33948% 71.7101%,
        88.97114% 72.5%,
        88.47124% 73.21394%,
        87.85495% 73.83022%,
        87.14102% 74.33013%,
        52.5% 94.33013%,
        51.7101% 94.69846%,
        50.86824% 94.92404%,
        50% 95%,
        49.13176% 94.92404%,
        48.2899% 94.69846%,
        47.5% 94.33013%,
        12.85898% 74.33013%,
        12.14505% 73.83022%,
        11.52876% 73.21394%,
        11.02886% 72.5%,
        10.66052% 71.7101%,
        10.43495% 70.86824%,
        10.35898% 70%,
        10.35898% 30%,
        10.43495% 29.13176%,
        10.66052% 28.2899%,
        11.02886% 27.5%,
        11.52876% 26.78606%,
        12.14505% 26.16978%,
        12.85898% 25.66987%
    );
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.profile-image-outer{
    background: #1D2333;
    width: 360px;
    height: 360px;
    clip-path: polygon(
        47.5% 5.66987%,
        48.2899% 5.30154%,
        49.13176% 5.07596%,
        50% 5%,
        50.86824% 5.07596%,
        51.7101% 5.30154%,
        52.5% 5.66987%,
        87.14102% 25.66987%,
        87.85495% 26.16978%,
        88.47124% 26.78606%,
        88.97114% 27.5%,
        89.33948% 28.2899%,
        89.56505% 29.13176%,
        89.64102% 30%,
        89.64102% 70%,
        89.56505% 70.86824%,
        89.33948% 71.7101%,
        88.97114% 72.5%,
        88.47124% 73.21394%,
        87.85495% 73.83022%,
        87.14102% 74.33013%,
        52.5% 94.33013%,
        51.7101% 94.69846%,
        50.86824% 94.92404%,
        50% 95%,
        49.13176% 94.92404%,
        48.2899% 94.69846%,
        47.5% 94.33013%,
        12.85898% 74.33013%,
        12.14505% 73.83022%,
        11.52876% 73.21394%,
        11.02886% 72.5%,
        10.66052% 71.7101%,
        10.43495% 70.86824%,
        10.35898% 70%,
        10.35898% 30%,
        10.43495% 29.13176%,
        10.66052% 28.2899%,
        11.02886% 27.5%,
        11.52876% 26.78606%,
        12.14505% 26.16978%,
        12.85898% 25.66987%
    );
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.profile-image{
    background: #1D2333;
    width: 340px;
    height: 340px;
    clip-path: polygon(
        47.5% 5.66987%,
        48.2899% 5.30154%,
        49.13176% 5.07596%,
        50% 5%,
        50.86824% 5.07596%,
        51.7101% 5.30154%,
        52.5% 5.66987%,
        87.14102% 25.66987%,
        87.85495% 26.16978%,
        88.47124% 26.78606%,
        88.97114% 27.5%,
        89.33948% 28.2899%,
        89.56505% 29.13176%,
        89.64102% 30%,
        89.64102% 70%,
        89.56505% 70.86824%,
        89.33948% 71.7101%,
        88.97114% 72.5%,
        88.47124% 73.21394%,
        87.85495% 73.83022%,
        87.14102% 74.33013%,
        52.5% 94.33013%,
        51.7101% 94.69846%,
        50.86824% 94.92404%,
        50% 95%,
        49.13176% 94.92404%,
        48.2899% 94.69846%,
        47.5% 94.33013%,
        12.85898% 74.33013%,
        12.14505% 73.83022%,
        11.52876% 73.21394%,
        11.02886% 72.5%,
        10.66052% 71.7101%,
        10.43495% 70.86824%,
        10.35898% 70%,
        10.35898% 30%,
        10.43495% 29.13176%,
        10.66052% 28.2899%,
        11.02886% 27.5%,
        11.52876% 26.78606%,
        12.14505% 26.16978%,
        12.85898% 25.66987%
    );
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.profile-image img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
.progress-bar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    background: transparent;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-top: -5px;
}
.progress {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: transparent;
}
.progress .track,
.progress .fill {
    fill: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    stroke-width: 30;
    transform: translate(75px, 685px) rotate(-90deg);
}
.progress .track {
    stroke: #293249;
}
.progress .fill {
    stroke: #5BD853;
    stroke-linecap: round;
    stroke-dasharray: 2160;
    stroke-dashoffset: 2160;
    transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s;
    stroke-linejoin: round; /*Added this css*/
}
.progress.blue .fill {
    stroke: #5BD853;
    stroke-linejoin: round; /*Added this css*/
}
```

```html
<div class="user-avatar-holder">
        <div class="progress-bar">
            <svg class="progress blue noselect" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 776 628">
                <path class="track" d="M723 314L543 625.77 183 625.77 3 314 183 2.23 543 2.23 723 314z"></path>
                <path class="fill" d="M723 314L543 625.77 183 625.77 3 314 183 2.23 543 2.23 723 314z"></path>
            </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="profile-image-outer">
            <div class="profile-image">
                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1025804/pexels-photo-1025804.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" alt="" width="500" height="500" >
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: it worked, one more question in user-avatar-holder class clip path, how can i change the hexagon radius size?

Answer (score 0):

With the help of css you can make rounded corner of any shape. i will shear you small script for making hexagonal shape below

```
<a href="http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/bhGn4/" target="blank">CSS rotate no svg alternative</a>
<br />
<svg class="svg-graphic" width="560" height="645" viewBox="0 0 560 645" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
    <g>
        <clipPath id="hex-mask">
            <polygon points="270,0 0,160 0,485 270,645 560,485 560,160"></polygon>
        </clipPath>
    </g>
    <polygon fill="#23B8C4" points="268,0 0,158 0,483 268,644 558,483 558,158" transform="translate(1, 1)"></polygon> <a xlink:href="http://example.com" transform="scale(0.90) translate(32, 38)">     
                   <polygon fill="#2B6674" points="268,0 0,158 0,483 268,644 558,483 558,158" transform="translate(1, 1)"></polygon>
     <image clip-path="url(#hex-mask)" height="100%" width="100%" xlink:href="http://s29.postimg.org/4d5vaqymf/2cd961b.jpg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice"></image>
    </a>

</svg>
```

Css for making rounded corner. customise value according to your need

```
polygon{
border-radius: 25px;
  background: #73AD21;
  padding: 20px; 
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;  
}
```